# Input from text file (Eg: [[1,2],[3,4]]) into 2d list in python

Tags: python, list, file, input

I have an input dataset in .txt format which looks like,

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

How do I read it into a 3-d python list where the first index is the line no. such as,

```
list[0][0][0] = 1


list[1][1][2] = 12
```

Comment: is every line in your .txt made of a list of two lists each with three items?

Comment: No, but the number is fixed @Reedinationer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with open` with a loop to get each line and use `ast.literal_eval` to get it into a list, then append it into the `l_3d` list:

```
import ast
l_3d = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l_3d.append(ast.literal_eval(line.rstrip()))
```

Thanks to @khachik :-), you can do the same thing just with `json.loads`:

```
import json
l_3d = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l_3d.append(json.loads(line.rstrip()))
```

And now in both cases:

```
print(l_3d)
```

Is:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

Comment: it looks like an alternative for `literal_eval` could be `json.loads`.

Comment: @Sankarshana Happy to help, :-), , after you reach 15 reputation you can up-vote :-)

Comment: Yeah sure I will @U9-Forward

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import json
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
datalist = data.split('\n')
blank = []
for i in range(len(datalist)):
    blank.append(json.loads(datalist[i]))
blank[1][1][1]
```